# importing the data from XLS file to php with simple coding

Tags: php, excel, excel-2007

I have the excel file with the following fields

```
First   Middle  Last    Email
michael j   jackson michael@plantgenomesciences.com
mary    j   watson  mary@microsoft.com
jeff    a   bridges jeff@rediff.com
nick    h   gill    nick@gill.com
```

If possible please tell me how can i get the data from Name Box (K8) from the same file

I want to know how can import this data into the php (I m able to upload the excel file on the server)

by using simple code (not any premade script)

Comment: You're going to have real problems reading the data from an Excel BIFF file unless you're willing to use a "premade" library like PHPExcel... basically, you're going to have to learn the complexities of the binary file format and write that library yourself... that could be several years of work for you. Why refuse to use a "premade script" when somebody else has already taken that time and effort to produce a library in order to save you that effort?

Comment: 1 route you can take, use Javascript ActiveXObject, and then use a ajax post to send the cell data you want to a php page for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically for files like spreadsheets, CSV import is most used. You can export excel file to csv. and then import it using PHP.

See http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

But it seems you are looking to read excel files, you may need help of third-party libraries for that. You also have a look at the following article:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/

Comment: Note that the IBM link describes how to read Excel 2007 spreadsheetML XML files rather than the more common BIFF file format, which would probably mean saving the Excel as XML rather than BIFF before uploading. If that's necessary, then it's easier to save as CSV rather than spreadsheetML

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just presented it as an alternative approach.

Comment: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:///C:/Windows/Temp/phpBB74.tmp" in D:\AppServ\www\excel1\index.php on line 75... I got this error. (I'll uploading all the files to linux once everything is working)

Comment: @Dave I used it some time back and it was working well at that time. You may get some help here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php

Comment: But again, if xml serves your pupose, CSV might also will. And it would be lot easier to use CSV.

Comment: Thanks RubyDev, I'll try to work on your solution. You mean to say I need to convert the file from xls to csv, then rest of the things. Right ?

Comment: Yes, thats most simple and popular method.

Comment: Thanks RubyDev, it worked :) 
Please tell me if I have to grab the data from only one particular then how can I go for that ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to write any simple code to read a BIFF file yourself in any reasonable timeframe. Your only quick solution, given an unwillingness to use a library capable of reading BIFF files, is to convert it to a different format (such as CSV) **before** uploading it.

Alternatively, if you're on a windows server, you could try using [PHP's COM](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) extension (as long as you install MS Excel on your server)

Comment: @RubyDev - I'd have suggested UNO with Open Office as well, but that's more complex to configure, and requires a third-party library interface from PHP to UNO as well (PUNO)... but it's an interesting new variant approach which is multi-platform

Comment: PHPExcel (you suggested in the comment above) also seems like a good choice.

Comment: @RubjDev - Thanks, I'd always recommend PHPExcel, but I do have a vested interest (as the developer) :-)